# Distribute large build across many build agents

Tags: tfs, build, msbuild, tfsbuild, hyper-v

I have a large solution, with many projects and many files, and only one build configuration, Release. I am using TFS, and the complete rebuild takes like 2 hours.

Is it possible to distribute the build across several agents, so that they will compile different projects, or, even better, different files? Something like dictcc? I can distribute the build on up to 10+ different machines, but the build only works on one.

For now, my impression is that agents can only have specialized jobs, like build, run tests, etc, but not split and distribute only one build.

I already tried optimizing the build, but still the project is big and can benefit on parallel build

Comment: It might make more sense to split the application into multiple, discrete chunks and build them separately.

Comment: the title was edited, but I am using TFS. The question is, how can I do this split on TFS? We already have several projects that can be run in parallel, but still, if I build on a single machine, it takes the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can *but* but must roll-up your sleeves: there is no built-in template that helps, but [Jim explains](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2010/09/14/parallelized-builds-with-tfs2010.aspx) how to make one.

Do not forget that you can also leverage multi-CPU/Core as explained in [Building Multiple Projects in Parallel with MSBuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb651793.aspx).

Comment: I saw both links, but still, the build of one platform/configuration is on one agent. I would like to split the build on several agents, something like distcc is doing.

Comment: In any case you need to refactor your build using one or more techniques: split the single solution; add previously built assemblies to referencepath; produce and use NuGet packages. I would favor the latter above all.

Comment: @GiulioVian That was my thought as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option would be to break your solution down into defunct components that can be built separately.

If you seperate each bit and build and test before publishing as Nuget you can distribute easily across build servers and even only build the bits that have changed.

This process will also work in the new build system coming in 2015 that does not use XAML.